# How to export Kotlin functions to Javascript with correct name

Tags: javascript, export, kotlin

I'm trying to export Kotlin functions to Javascript. The problem is, functions which require arguments are renamed after Kotlin2JS operation, here's an example:

Kotlin source:

```
fun withParam(args: String) {
    println("JavaScript generated through Kotlin")
}

fun withoutParams() {
    println("Without params")
}
```

After Kotlin2JS, trying to require in Node REPL:

```
> const kotlinBundle = require('./build/index.js');
undefined
> kotlinBundle
{ 'withParam_61zpoe$': [Function: withParam],
  withoutParams: [Function: withoutParams] }
>
```

As you can see, function with argument got exported with `_61zpoe$` suffix. Is it possible to get rid of that part?

I'm using `kotlin2js` plugin and `kotlin-stdlib-js:1.1.1` library, my `kotlinOptions` are:

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
  moduleKind = "commonjs"
  outputFile = "build/index.js"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @JsName annotation to provide exact name for the function (or other symbol) in compiled javascript.
I.e.

```
@JsName("withParam")    
fun withParam(args: String) {
      println("JavaScript generated through Kotlin")
}
```